# How to log into a page and print a class

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

First of all. I have no experience with python. I have only coded C++, and am now trying to learn python. So I do this as an exercise to learn Python better and at the same time make a program I will be using in practice.

Now to explain my problem: What I am trying to do is log into a site. And I want a page on that site to print some HTML code.

What I have already tried:

cookiejar: I came into a problem with my parameters(a parameter to soup) not being of the right type. Another post suggested using .enode to make it into utf-8.

My problem is that I can't get to log into the page I want to. Not even facebook. (when I tried facebook i changed the payload to "mail" and "pass")

So what the code is trying to do is first to get a session, and log in with that session. Then I try to scrape the "requestUrl" HTML and write out its html code. But instead, I get this

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>parent.top.location.href='index.php?feilpassord=ja';</script>"
```

Code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

username = 'username'
password = 'password'


loginUrl = 'https://mafiaspillet.no/'

requestUrl = 'https://mafiaspillet.no/game.php?p=spillere'



payload = {
    'brukernavn' : username,
    'passord' : password
}

with requests.Session() as session:
        post = session.post(loginUrl, data=payload)
        r = session.get(requestUrl)
        print(r.text)
```

When I ran the code I expected it to write out the HTML code of "requestUrl". But instead, it gave me just some javascript.

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>parent.top.location.href='index.php?feilpassord=ja';</script>"
```

"feilpassord=ja" from right above means "wrongpassword=yes" in english.

Comment: "It failed me", "don't work either for some reason" and "it gave me an error" are not helpful problem descriptions.

Comment: Removed those that was unhelpful.

Comment: I'm struggling to follow the english. There need to be more detailed explanations of what is happening or what you want

Comment: Sorry... :/ I have edited again. Is my problem easier to understand now?

Comment: @MrKrisey What I meant was that you should post the relevant code, error message, and possible tracebacks. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for details

Comment: your objective is: given a web address enter login details and then print the logged in pages's html code?

Comment: Yes. I want to print out html code that is only avaible when logged in.

Comment: your request url gives me 404 Not Found. Which page are you exactly looking to get the html?

Comment: I changed it now. The requestUrl "https://mafiaspillet.no/game.php?p=spillere" is only aviable if you are logged into the site.